# The opposite of events and delegates?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

This might sound weird, but I am just experimenting with the thought of it. I was wondering about subscribing functions to different classes. So i have a base or static location where my method is held, and without relying on inheritance, am i able to subscribe that function to an object?

For example:
Action class has a method class SendKeys
I have three objects called Textbox and Button and Textarea
Realistically i don't want them all to have access to SendKeys function, just Textbox, and Textarea. But i also don't want to copy paste the SendKeys code over and over again.

I could create a static class that takes the data and the two objects will call that static class, but that just seems like extra work and i would be creating the function anyways in order to call an external function.

The best solution i have is to just copy paste code. but i was wondering if i could subscribe specific functions. Its like the opposite of what an event and delegate can do right? Cause the subscription requires code in the class of the subscriber. I kind of think i want partial classes? I am not sure. Thoughts?

A deeper dive into the issue:
I have a bunch of different elements to work with here are some basic ones, it goes deeper when you take into account custom elements:
Button
Textbox
Textarea
MultiSelect
SingleSelect
RadioButtons
Checkboxes
MenuItems
PasswordTextboxes
ETC

Each one of these would have their own actions that can be applied. For example they all would have the same properties like GetAttribute or GetCssValue but i don't want to be sending keys to a checkbox, so i dont want to have the ability to have that function when creating inheritance.  BUT, i do want other objects to have those functions. The code is lengthy and a bunch of copy pasting code is ugly. I was hoping i can subscribe functnions to objects. So i can say something like Actions.Click(Textbox) or Textbox.Click or w.e but i cannot do Actions.SendKeys(button, "fdsaf") or Button.SendKeys("fdsaf")

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about static [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: @user1538301 yes but he still have to copy paste it for each object as he do not want any derived class.

Comment: Actual that is a neater solution, but still requires copy paste.

Comment: Textbox and Textarea could inherit from EditableControl while button just inherit from Control. I'm currently playing with ECS and this would work in that pattern.

Comment: if i could do something like this: public static void SendKeys(this Textbox pTextbox, this TextArea pTextArea, string pValue) that would be fine. but unfortunately, i cannot

Comment: @the_lotus unfortunately thats a limited solution, when i dig deep into the different types of elements there are too many configurations in order for that to be a solution.

Comment: @AndrewMills maybe you could explain a more complication scenario.

Comment: @AndrewMills Then it's an X Y problem you describe. You are trying to fix a problem (X) and you think (Y) is the solution so you are asking about how to fix Y not X

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to give methods to _a few very specific_ classes, without code duplication. Is that it?

Comment: There are c# webforms frameworks (ext.net, telerik) that do use a base class for all editable components (textfield, textarea, etc). Why you say this is a limited solution?

Comment: @Franck @AndrewMills I don't think you can choose not to have a derived type and not copy and paste ;). I also don't see why you can't use an interface and write some static method that acts on that instead of on two different types of classes. Presumably `Textarea` and `Textbox` have many of the same members, much like HTML <inputs> and <textareas> have many of the same properties, and presumably, `SendKeys` is going to access the same members regardless of the underlying concrete type, not sure why that isn't the solution here. It's the only way without copying and pasting or inheritance

Comment: @Sweeper essentially yes, there are simple and ugly solutions like copy paste but i was wondering if there was an elegant solution like events and delegates

Comment: i could built an internal static class that houses all the actions, or even extension methods. Still requires copy paste even if its as minimal as implementing an interface that calls the static method. Just thought there might be a better way :/ oh well. thanks all for the quick responses.

Comment: Copy and paste will always be necessary, but implementing DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself -- means that the duplication is reduced to just the right level.  If you're really interested in reducing code to the max, look into LISP (CLOS) and in the opposite shape, Forth and Factor.  All of these languages have zero syntax, and therefore great at metaprogramming, and therefore macros, and therefore also writing DSL's (domain specific languages).

Comment: So, to be more direct, can events and delegates be more direct?  I once wrote an application that was data-dictionary driven, and a lot could be automated and derived from the datatypes, and I was still using copy-and-paste, but it was to fill a table (equivalent to declarative code like YAML).  That is along the lines of what I imagine you are trying to do.

Comment: Another aspect of LISP and Forth/Factor is homoiconicity, the fact that there is one basic shape of code, and that the language for metaprogramming and creating macros is the same as the language being created.  This means you don't have to learn two languages, as in C / C++.  This also means that you have the full power of the language with which to generate code.